# Trouble with Double Quotation Marks in Google Scholar Search Query

Tags: double, google-scholar

I'm having trouble using the code below in Google Scholar. The double quotation marks around "data availability" aren't appearing in the search query. Does anyone have any solutions for this problem?

## r script

```r
search_pre="(\"osf.io\" OR \"data availability\")"

journal=paste(" source:'","The Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences","'",sep="")

search<-paste('https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=',search_pre,journal,sep="")

browseURL(search)

# I also tried the following scripts, also doesn't work 
search_pre="('osf.io' OR 'data availability')"

journal=paste(" source:'","The Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences","'",sep="")

search<-paste('https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=',search_pre,journal,sep="")

browseURL(search)
```